Export a GraphQL collection in Postman
Is it possible to export a GraphQL collection?
When I right-click on a regular collection there is an 'export' option, but right-clicking on a GraphQL collection lacks this option.
Is it still somehow possible?

I guess the only option is to use "Plain Collection" with POST requests and "GraphQL" Body. In that way you can export a collection. The limitations are inability to use subscriptions and bad schema support.

I'm starting to get the feeling that you're right.
The POST thing doesn't really work for me so I'll probably end up finding a different app for testing my GQL Api.

After digging around some more I've come to the conclusion that Postman simply can't export GraphQL collections.
However, in the proccess I stumbeld upon Bruno. This Postman alternative looks very prommissing since it stores all data in any given directory so you can just put it in git alongside the rest of your code (without even having to export everything!). Also the fact that you don't need an account to work with it is a nice bonus in my opinion.
At the moment I'm moving my GraphQL project to Bruno, but the regular REST part of Bruno looks promissing as well!
